# Telling Mathematica to treat square roots as real valued

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I often deal with problems which I know are real-valued, but Mathematica skips some simplifications because it doesn't know which branch of `Sqrt` to take. Is there some generic way to tell it to treat all `Sqrt` (and perhaps other multibranch functions?) that inputs and outputs are real-valued, for the purpose of `Simplify`?

Motivation -- I was looking to compute $F_\infty(s)$ where $F$ is defined as follows:

$$F_n(s)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2s/k^3}}$$

This doesn't evaluate in Mathematica, however, a user [found](https://mathoverflow.net/a/402932/7655) that bringing square root inside the product makes it solvable:

`1/Sqrt[Product[1 + (2 s)/k^3, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]] // FullSimplify`

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(1-\sqrt[3]{-2} \sqrt[3]{s}\right) \Gamma \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{s}+1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{i \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{s}}{2^{2/3}}+1\right)}}}$$

The downside is that `FullSimplify` doesn't remove the reciprocals. On other hand, manually switching $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ operations lets `FullSimplify` cancel out the reciprocals (and `ToRadicals` simplifies it further)

`Sqrt[1/Product[1 + (2 s)/k^3, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]] // FullSimplify // ToRadicals`

$$\sqrt{\Gamma \left(1-\sqrt[3]{-2} \sqrt[3]{s}\right) \Gamma \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{s}+1\right) \Gamma \left((-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{s}+1\right)}$$

Comment: `Product[1/Sqrt[1 + (2 s)/k^3], {k, 1, n}]` evaluates fine in version 12.3.1. It gives a horrible answer though, much worse than `Product[(1 + (2 s)/k^3)^a, {k, 1, n}]` where we can substitute `a -> -1/2`.

Comment: Does `Surd[..., 2]` help?

Comment: @murray using `Surd` doesn't help, it seems to follow same simplification rules as `Sqrt`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Refine[ToRadicals@FullSimplify[PowerExpand[1/Sqrt[Product[1 + (2 s)/k^3, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]]], Assumptions -> Element[s, Reals]]]// TraditionalForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Product[1/Sqrt[expr],...] ==Sqrt[Product[1/expr],...]. Than problem of branches doesn't appear.

```
Sqrt[Product[1/(1 + (2 s)/k^3), {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]] // 
       FullSimplify // ToRadicals

(*   Sqrt[Gamma[1 - (-2)^(1/3) s^(1/3)] Gamma[1 + 2^(1/3) s^(1/3)] Gamma[
     1 + (-1)^(2/3) 2^(1/3) s^(1/3)]]   *)
```